# How to retrieve the RSSI with Web Bluetooth?

Tags: rssi, web-bluetooth

I read on old forums that it was not possible to obtain the RSSI of one or more BLE devices with Web Bluetooth.
Can we now get RSSI with Web Bluetooth?
If yes, how can we do it?
Thanks in advance.
Joe

Comment: If your client supports it, then [yes](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#advertising-events)!

Answer (score 1):

The [Web Bluetooth Scanning API](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetoothadvertisingevent-rssi) exposes bluetooth advertisements data such as RSSI.

This API is not enabled by default in Chrome as we speak though as implementation work is not complete yet. You'll need to enable the `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` flag to play with it. See sample at https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/scan.html